# Parse date with 7 digits in microseconds part

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to parse Atom feed and it contains date like this one

```
2019-02-28T06:11:12.0775241Z
```

The problem with it is microseconds 0775241, which is 7 digits, but php can handle only 6 digits. This date is probably generated with Go lang.

If it had 6 digits, Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z would work fine.

UPD: it is for DateTime::createFromFormat, can't use new DateTime etc.

Looking for solution, may be you had same problem as me.

Comment: `new DateTime("2019-02-28T06:11:12.0775241Z");` woks well for me

Comment: Also `strtotime` works

Comment: Is this for usage in `DateTime::createFromFormat()`?

Comment: Yes, it for createFromFormat

Comment: If you do not need to use that specifically, you can use the two other suggestions, which should work just fine - alternatively just trim away that excessive number.

Comment: You can do `$str = substr($str, 0, -2) . substr($str, -1)` if the length of the string is 28 char instead of regular 27

Answer (score 2):

That is a standard easily recognisable date format. Use the DateTime class

```
$d = new DateTime("2019-02-28T06:11:12.0775241Z");
echo $d->format('d/m/y H:i:s');
```

RESULT

```
28/02/19 06:11:12
```

Of course you can output in any format you like

Comment: I parse rss and people use dates in different formats. I need to use $test = \DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date); but not new DateTime, as it can be not date at all

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the best solution but you can handle it with [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

```
$datetime = Carbon::parse('2019-03-13T18:07:54.5810814+03:30');
dump($datetime);

// Carbon @1552487874 {#358
//    date: 2019-03-13 18:07:54.581081 +03:30
// }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the format `'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u?\Z'`

More info at the link [DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimeimmutable.createfromformat.php)

```php
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u?\Z', '2019-02-28T06:11:12.0775241Z');
```

The result of `var_export($dateTime)` is

```php
\DateTime::__set_state(array(
   'date' => '2019-02-28 06:11:12.077524',
   'timezone_type' => 3,
   'timezone' => 'UTC',
))
```

Also you can use `$dateTime = date_create('2019-02-28T06:11:12.0775241Z');` if you need to avoid `Exception` in case of an error.